# mysql_query() Access denied for user

Tags: php, mysql

I'm making a PHP and MySQL RPG game, and my changeEquipment page is not working. I'm getting these errors:

> Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: Access denied for user
>   'devinfa1'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in
>   /home/devinfa1/public_html/spellsword/changeEquipment.php on line 21
>
> Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: A link to the server
>   could not be established in
>   /home/devinfa1/public_html/spellsword/changeEquipment.php on line 21
>
> Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: Access denied for user
>   'devinfa1'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in
>   /home/devinfa1/public_html/spellsword/changeEquipment.php on line 27
>
> Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: A link to the server
>   could not be established in
>   /home/devinfa1/public_html/spellsword/changeEquipment.php on line 27

Here's my code:

```
<?php
// Get commonFunctions.php
require_once('commonFunctions.php');

// Start the session and connect to the database
session_start();
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","devinfa1_user","dbpass");
if (!$con) { die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); }
mysql_select_db("devinfa1_spellsword", $con);   

// If logged in
if(isset($_SESSION['account_name'])) {
    // If form is submitted
    if(isset($_POST['submit']) || isset($_POST['submit_x'])) {

        // If the hero has more than one weapon
        if(hero_has_multiple_weapons()) {
            // Set new weapon
            mysql_query("UPDATE Hero_Weapons SET active_weapon = TRUE WHERE HW_hero_id =
                (SELECT hero_id FROM Heroes WHERE hero_name = '$_SESSION[hero_name]')
                AND HW_item_id = (SELECT item_id FROM Items WHERE item_name = '$_POST[weapon]')");

            // Unset previous weapon
            if(isset($_SESSION['hero_name'])) {
                mysql_query("UPDATE Hero_Weapons SET active_weapon = FALSE WHERE HW_hero_id =
                    (SELECT hero_id FROM Heroes WHERE hero_name = '$_SESSION[hero_name]')
                    AND HW_item_id = (SELECT item_id FROM Items WHERE item_name = '$_SESSION[weapon_name]')");
            }
        }

// Close the database connection
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

So, the PHP should be connecting to my databse using the `devinfa1_user` username and `dbpass` password, but it's apparently trying to use the `devinfa1` username with no password.

I have no idea why this is the case, because I have the exact same connection code and an update statement on my changeHero page and it works perfectly. Any ideas?

Comment: is there some code in the commonFunctions.php that is doing any db stuff?

Comment: yes. commonFunctions.php has the hero_has_multiple_weapons() function

Comment: see my answer, i believe that is where your issue lies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the connection in with the query,  per the manual : The MySQL connection. If the link identifier is not specified, the last link opened by mysql_connect() is assumed. If no such link is found, it will try to create one as if mysql_connect() was called with no arguments. If no connection is found or established, an E_WARNING level error is generated.

see if that works, it looks as if is overriding the last connection (ie in the call to hero_has_multiple_weapons() a db connection is opened) or your last connection didnt really connect

Comment: i figured it out. I was closing the connection at the end of the hero_has_multiple_weapons function. Thanks for the help

Comment: No problem, love helping and getting help when needed.  Congrats